# How to timeout flash messages in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, alert

I currently have standard flash messages with the devise gem for success/failure etc.  I have added the option to manually close the message with some bootstrap functionality via a close class.  A small snippet is shown below.

```
{ 
  <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&#215;</a>
  <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
}
```

I was would like to have an option to create a timeout period where the alert message would close on its one after 5 seconds.  Not sure if there is a simple way to do this in Rails.

Thanks

Comment: javascript's `setTimeout` method is your friend.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you've jQuery loaded in the same page, this will work for you

```
<div id="flash">
  <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&#215;</a>
  <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#flash').remove();
  }, 5000);
 })
</script>
```

Comment: Where should this go? I tried to add it to my `application.js` and my `_header.html.erb` but it did not work. Just for information, I do have jQuery working in my app, thanks to `//= require jquery //= require jquery.turbolinks //= require jquery_ujs` in `application.js`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Though not ideal place for javascript, you can put the whole snippet in your layout file. I, usually, put markup in a partial, include that in the layouts (e.g. application.html.*) and put the javascript in a js file and include that in the javascript manifest file.

Answer (score 2):

Using vanilla Javascript in Rails 6 (placing code in `app/javascript/packs/application.js`), I used the following to fade a flash message with a `'.notification'` class.

First, add a `notification` class to your html. Then, in CSS, set `.notification` opacity to 1 with a `transition` set to `ease-in-out`. Then, with JS, add the `.fade` class to `.notification`, which sets the opacity to 0.

JS

```
window.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
  hideNotice();
});

function hideNotice() {
  const notification = document.querySelector('.notification')
  if (notification) {
    setInterval(function() {
      notification.classList.add('fade');
    }, 5000);
  }
}
```

CSS

```
.notification {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.notification.fade {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this one worked for me. Is there a way to make it fade out instead of just disappear immediately?

Comment: @FelipeCerda Yes! Please see edit. This is as simple as adding a CSS class instead of setting display to 'none'.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure that your div has an `alert` class.
2. Add the following code in your `application.js` or other `.js` file:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.alert').fadeOut();
  }, 3000);
})
```

3. Watch it go away.