# setting timeout for flash message in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In rails, is it possible to set the timeout only for specific flash message based on the action and controller from which it is rendered? All the others flash messages should follow the default format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to timeout flash messages in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15577555/how-to-timeout-flash-messages-in-rails)

Comment: Yes, it's possible in javascript, based on action type you can do. But I have no idea on ruby-on-rails concept.

Answer (score 0):

**This will work**

```
<div style="margin-left: 26%; margin-right: 26%; text-align: center" id="flash">
      <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
        <div style="margin-top: 20px"> <%= content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert alert-#{message_type}") %></div>
      <% end %>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#flash').remove();
        }, 3000);
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).